# What is the Slope of the Tangent Line with the Equation $2(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}=25(x^{2}-y^{2})$ at the Point $(-3,1)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am faced with the following question:

> Find the slope of the tangent line to the lemniscate with equation
>   $2(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2} = 25(x^{2}-y^{2})$ at the point $(-3,1)$.

So far, I have made the following steps:

1) Find the derivative of the equation through use of the chain rule

2) This gives $4(x^{2}+y^{2})\cdot(2x+2y)-(25(2x-2y))$

3) In the equation given in step 2, fill in all $x$ variables with $-3$ and all $y$ variables with $1$, which gives the answer of $-60$.

4) The slope is $-60$.

However, I am not sure that this is the correct slope.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to get the slope, or, if -60 is not the slope, how to find the actual slope?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution we will use techniques from multivariable calculus to find the slope. We will then create the tangent line and graph it using a computer algebra system, just to be sure.

I can't figure out how to format equations here, but to see this problem clearly worked out with explanations and beautiful graphs, go here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f5jPEhixb5E5zuAHOmEiuIor80PCn0pW8JD4rIAofi0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

the first derivative should be
$$[4(x^2+y^2)*(2x+2yy')]-(25(2x+2yy'))$$
use the point (-3,1)
$$[4(9+1)*(-6+2y')]-(25(-6+2y'))$$
then find the y' and find the tangent equation

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to calculate the first derivative at the point of tangency and write the equation of the line as:

$y=y_{0}+(\frac{dy}{dx})(x-x_{0})$.

The first derivative is:

$y’=-\frac{f_{x}}{f_{y}}=-\frac{x(4x^{2}+4y^{2}-25)}{y(4x^{2}+4y^{2}+25)}$

that calculated at the point $(-3,1)$, allows you to write the equation of the line equal to:

$y=\frac{9x}{13}+\frac{40}{13}$.